# Does cancan authorize! authorize related model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

If I have model User and Bascinfo, and User has_one Basicinfo.
will:

```
authorize! :show, user
```

also authorize show user.basicinfo?

Thanks!

Comment: if you have installed CanCan, then you try and you tell us!

Comment: Yes, I tried, it can not authorize related model. Seems the only way is authorize manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this wiki link on cancan, It could help you. https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions

Comment: I did follow the wiki, but it not mentions relate model. I even created a issue: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/930